# Found a some JSON Logical Operator in a Chat API, How does this work

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I was looking to implement a user chat feature in a personal project and found an API with the following piece of code. All I understand is that it is JSON. Can Anyone explain it to me.

```
let qry = {  $or: 
  [
    {
      $and: [
        { receiver_id: req.user._id, sender_id: req.body.receiver_id },
      ],
    },
    {
      $and: [
        { receiver_id: req.body.receiver_id },
        { sender_id: req.user._id },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: It's not JSON. It's JS object. What exactly you want to be explained?

Comment: *"All I understand is that it is JSON"* No, it isn't. It's a JavaScript object literal. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) It looks like something that could be sent to some data store to do a query.

Comment: As others have mentioned its a JS object - but it seems to adhere to the standards/format of a mongodb documents query: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/ - in case you were wondering what type of object it is

Comment: sorry, I'm very new to this.But I get it now. Thanks, A lot everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, It is a query which uses $or operator. The syntax of using or operator is :

```
{ $or: [ { <expression1> }, { <expression2> }, ... , { <expressionN> } ] }
```

therefore, you can see the $and operator are the independent expression, the one which comes out to be true will be taken in account.

More information you should look at its documentation:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/

Comment: I'm using MongoDB in a backend project. I get it now. Thanks A lot for the explanation!